# difference between click and tap in Android

Tags: android, gesture

The [GestureDetector.OnGestureListener][1] class has the method  [onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent)][2]:

> Notified When a tap Occurs with the up MotionEvent que triggered it.

This method has the same  onclick's function? Can I use this method to implement the same behavior I want from the onclick method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests and it seems that the answer is **YES**, you may use onSingleTapUp instead of onclick. The onSingleTapUp method can differentiate well a simple click of a double or long click. My test:

```
public class MainFragmentScrollerController
{
    private MainFragment mFragment;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;

    public MainFragmentScrollerController(MainFragment fragment)
    {
        mFragment = fragment;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(mFragment.getActivity(), new GestureListener());
    }

    public void setGestureListener()
    {
        mFragment.myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                boolean gestureResult = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                Log.i("GestureListener", "gestureResult = " + gestureResult);
                return gestureResult;
            }
        });
    }

    public class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        private final String TAG = "GestureListener";
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScroll: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Result for simple click:

```
09-04 14:20:58.040: D/GestureListener(17689): onDown: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=188.71875, y[0]=26.0625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34463725, downTime=34463725, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:20:58.040: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = true
09-04 14:20:58.100: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:20:58.130: D/GestureListener(17689): onSingleTapUp: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=188.71875, y[0]=26.0625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34463811, downTime=34463725, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:20:58.130: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = true
```

Result for long click:

```
09-04 14:22:12.520: D/GestureListener(17689): onDown: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=179.22656, y[0]=41.0625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34538199, downTime=34538199, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:22:12.520: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = true
09-04 14:22:12.560: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:12.930: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:12.950: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:13.010: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:13.100: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:13.130: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:13.150: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:13.180: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
09-04 14:22:13.200: D/GestureListener(17689): onLongPress: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=179.22656, y[0]=41.0625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34538199, downTime=34538199, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:22:13.230: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = false
```

Result for fling:

```
09-04 14:24:09.650: D/GestureListener(17689): onDown: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=332.15625, y[0]=2.625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34655337, downTime=34655337, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:24:09.650: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = true
09-04 14:24:09.690: D/GestureListener(17689): onScroll: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=332.15625, y[0]=2.625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34655337, downTime=34655337, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=331.9604, y[0]=-72.36835, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=34655368, downTime=34655337, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:24:09.690: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = true
09-04 14:24:09.710: D/GestureListener(17689): onScroll: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=332.15625, y[0]=2.625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34655337, downTime=34655337, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=337.91425, y[0]=-124.40411, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=34655385, downTime=34655337, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:24:09.710: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = true
09-04 14:24:09.730: D/GestureListener(17689): onFling: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=332.15625, y[0]=2.625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34655337, downTime=34655337, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=337.91425, y[0]=-124.40411, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=34655414, downTime=34655337, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
09-04 14:24:09.730: I/GestureListener(17689): gestureResult = true
```